# Delete-deny Permissions to Users

Tags: windows-server-2003, permissions

I am in the need of a little assistance.

I have found that over the last view months that users delete or move data on the shares that must not be moved.

I need to change the permissions of the top level folder, and apply inheritance to lower level folders. The users must still be able to create, change folder/file names, read and write to it, list folder contents but must not be able to delete anything.

I did look into it and now I am a little bit stuck. If you select deny access to delete/delete subfolders and files, you cannot delete it (which is what I want) but when that option is selected, you cannot change a folder name that you just created (it stays at "New Folder" name), or any other folder already created. All the other options are marked to allow access.

And turning on the modify attribute does not help either. You still can't change the folder name.

Is there anyone that maybe has a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You're not going to be happy with using NTFS permissions to do what you're trying to do. When saving a changed document, some programs (in particular, various Microsoft Office programs) will create temporary files for saving the new document, and will then delete the original file and rename the temporary file. One program like that will throw a wrench into your plans.

If users can modify existing files they could always truncate a file to zero bytes, effectively deleting it, if not actually deleting it in fact.

It sounds like you'd be better served by using a versioning system such as a document control system or version control system, rather than just using a shared filesystem folder.